# How to `std::bind()` a standard library algorithm?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

The short version of my question is this: How can I use something like `std::bind()` with a standard library algorithm?

Since the short version is a bit devoid of details, here is a bit of an explanation: Assume I have the algorithms `std::transform()` and now I want to implement `std::copy()` (yes, I realize that there is `std::copy()` in the standard C++ library). Since I'm hideously lazy, I clearly want to use the existing implementation of `std::transform()`. I could, of course, do this:

```
struct identity {
    template <typename T>
    auto operator()(T&& value) const -> T&& { return std::forward<T>(value); }
};  
template <typename InIt, typename OutIt>
auto copy(InIt begin, InIt end, OutIt to) -> OutIt {
    return std::transform(begin, end, to, identity());
}
```

Somehow this implementation somewhat feels like a *configuration* of an algorithm. For example, it seems as if `std::bind()` should be able to do the job but simply using `std::bind()` doesn't work:

```
namespace P = std::placeholders;
auto copy = std::bind(std::transform, P::_1, P::_2, P::_3, identity());
```

The problem is that the compiler can't determine the appropriate template arguments from just the algorithm and it doesn't matter if there is an `&` or not. Is there something which can make an approach like using `std::bind()` work? Since this is looking forward, I'm happy with a solution working with anything which is already proposed for inclusion into the C++ standard. Also, to get away with my laziness I'm happy to do some work up front for later easier use. Think of it this way: in my role as a library *implementer*, I'll put things together once such that every library *user* can be lazy: I'm a busy implementer but a lazy user.

In case you want to have a ready-made test bed: here is a complete program.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

using namespace std::placeholders;

struct identity {
    template <typename T>
    T&& operator()(T&& value) const { return std::forward<T>(value); }
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> source{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    std::vector<int> target;

#ifdef WORKS
    std::transform(source.begin(), source.end(), std::back_inserter(target),
                   identity());
#else
    // the next line doesn't work and needs to be replaced by some magic
    auto copy = std::bind(&std::transform, _1, _2, _3, identity());
    copy(source.begin(), source.end(), std::back_inserter(target));
#endif
    std::copy(target.begin(), target.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Hey - that's a genuine question...! (sure, double objectives do play a role)

Comment: The tag combination was, what made me suspecting ;-) ... (and that's a good question of course)

Comment: Generic lambdas is pretty much the only thing I can think of, but I assume that's insufficiently `bind`-like...

Comment: You must have heard of the C++14 technique to pass an overload set via a generic lambda. What's wrong or insufficient with that approach?

Comment: @T.C.: actually, I indeed think that generic lambdas are cool but a comparatively blunt tool, at least, when using them as the binder. Since they yield objects they could be a viable approach for the alternative, though: create algorithm _function objects_ rather than _functions_.

Comment: @dyp: I still consider generic lambdas to pretty much writing the function rather than configuring it, at least, when used to do the binding.

Comment: Well, I meant some `#define WRAP_OVERLOAD_SET(FUNCTION) ([](auto&&... pp) -> decltype(auto) { return FUNCTION(std::forward<decltype(pp)>(pp)...); })`, then `std::bind(WRAP_OVERLOAD_SET(std::transform), P::_1, P::_2, P::_3, identity())`

Comment: @dyp: you want to use a _macro_? gee...! However, yes, that is closer to what I have in mind. Also, I'm currently trying to get something like that work and it seems the implementation I'm using isn't entirely happy with forwarding placeholders.

Comment: The only way *I* know to pass an overload set is as a function object. As you have noted, you could of course write the function object types yourself, e.g. `struct transform { template<typename... TT> decltype(auto) operator()(TT&&... tt) { return std::transform(std::forward<TT>(tt)...); } };` -- or, you could use global function *objects*, like `auto const transform = WRAP_OVERLOAD_SET(std::transform);`

Comment: Actually, the issues with placeholders was me getting things wrong. Well, you can create a function object implicitly or explicitly: `auto transform = [](auto&&... args){ ... };`

Comment: why use `auto foo() -> T&&`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When trying to `std::bind()` an overloaded function the compiler can't determine which overload to use: at the time the `bind()`-expression is evaluated the function arguments are unknown, i.e., overload resolution can't decide which overload to pick. There is no direct way in in C++ [yet?] to treat an overload set as an object. Function templates simply generate an overload set with one overload for each possible instantiation. That is, the entire problem of not being able to `std::bind()` any of the standard C++ library algorithms revolves around the fact that the standard library algorithms are function templates.

One approach to have the same effect as `std::bind()`ing an algorithm is to use C++14 *generic lambdas* to do the binding, e.g.:

```
auto copy = [](auto&&... args){
    return std::transform(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)..., identity());
};
```

Although this works it is actually equivalent to a fancy implementation of function template rather than configuring an existing function. However, using generic lambdas to create the primary function objects in a suitable standard library namespace could make the actual underlying function objects readily available, e.g.:

```
namespace nstd {
    auto const transform = [](auto&&... args){
        return std::transform(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args...));
    };
}
```

Now, with the approach to implementing `transform()` it is actually trivial to use `std::bind()` to build `copy()`:

```
auto copy = std::bind(nstd::transform, P::_1, P::_2, P::_3, identity());
```

Despite the looks and use of generic lambdas it is worth pointing out that it actually takes roughly the same effort to create corresponding function objects using only features available for C++11:

```
struct transform_t {
    template <typename... Args>
    auto operator()(Args&&... args) const
        -> decltype(std::transform(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...)) {
        return std::transform(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    }
};
constexpr transform_t transform{};
```

Yes, it is more typing but it is just a reasonable small constant factor over the use of generic lambdas, i.e., if the objects using generic lambdas the C++11 version is, too.

Of course, once we have function objects for the algorithms it may be neat to actually not even having to `std::bind()` them as we'd need to mention all the not bound arguments. In the example case it is [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) (well, I think currying only applies to binding the first argument but whether it's the first or the last argument seems a bit random). What if we had `curry_first()` and `curry_last()` to curry the first or the last argument? The implementation of `curry_last()` is trivial, too (for brevity I'm using a generic lambda but the same rewrite as above could be used to make it available with C++11):

```
template <typename Fun, typename Bound>
auto curry_last(Fun&& fun, Bound&& bound) {
    return [fun = std::forward<Fun>(fun),
            bound = std::forward<Bound>(bound)](auto&&... args){
        return fun(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)..., bound);
    };
}
```

Now, assuming that `curry_last()` lives in the same namespace a either `nstd::transform` or `identity()` the definition of `copy()` could become:

```
auto const copy = curry_last(nstd::transform, identity());
```

OK, maybe this question didn't get me any hat but maybe I'll get some support for turning our standard library algorithms into function objects and possibly adding a few cool approaches to creating bound versions of said algorithms. I think this approach is much saner (although in the form described above possibly not as complete) than some of the [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n4171.html)s in this area.

Comment: The existence of non standard extensions (even good ones) doesn't mean it is required in C++!  (a `constexpr` creation/move/copy constructor on a stateless lambda is not required by the standard.  Neither it is ruled out, if I remember rightly)

Comment: @Yakk: yes, I got tricked by an extension (actually only in gcc not in clang).

Comment: @Yakk lambdas may not appear in constant expressions, I think that rules out "it's allowed but not portable"

Comment: @dyp: yes, you are right. I changed them to be `const`. I don't quite like that, though: the can't be constructed prior to normal initialization which means even with C++14 the approach using proper function objects rather than generic lambdas needs to be used...

Comment: @Yakk Closure types are explicitly not literal types per [expr.prim.lambda]/p3, and `constexpr` object declarations requires literal types ([dcl.constexpr]/p9).

Comment: FYI, the main developper of [Boost.Hana](https://github.com/ldionne/hana) would also like to have constexpr lambdas in the next standard. See his [CppCon 2014](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L2SktfaJPuU) presentation. Yet I've not seen any proposal.